Haar measure and Lebesgue measure
Trying to prove the inversion theorem of Fourier transform i ended up in my final step with $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\hat{f}(\zeta)e^{2\pi i x\cdot \zeta}d\zeta=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}(f*\psi_\varepsilon)(x),$$ where $\psi_\varepsilon$ is a approximate identity. To conclude i need the convergence of the last limit to $f(x)$. I know it's true for $(\psi_\varepsilon*f)(x)$, and that is also true for $(f*\psi_\varepsilon)(x)$ in the case of locally abelian groups with left haar measure $\mu$ satisfying $$\mu(A)=\mu(A^{-1}),$$ for every measurable $A\subset G$. In my case $G=\mathbb{R}^n$ and the Haar measure is the usual Lebesgue measure, but i don't know what does it mean for $\mu(A^{-1})$ in my case. Thanks in advance!!

$A^{-1}={x: -x \in A}$.

so is just the reflected set?

Yes, the group operation is addition.

And trivially $\mu(A)=\mu(A^{-1})$ i suppose

If you use $\mu^*(A) = \inf\{\sum_{n\geq 0} \mu(B_n): A \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 0} B_n\}$ (where each $B_n$ is a product of intervals $[a^n_1,b^n_1]\times \ldots \times [a^n_n, b^n_n]$ and $\mu^*(B_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n(b^n_i-a^n_i)$) to define an outer measure, so that $\mu$ is defined to be its restriction to Borel measurable sets, then it is straight-forward to check that $\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(-E)$.
More generally, since inversion gives an isomorphism from $G$ to its opposite $G^{\text{op}}$, $\mu(A^{-1})$ is a right Haar measure on $G$, so $\mu(A) = \mu(A^{-1})$ if $G$ is unimodular, as is the case for any abelian group.
